# How to update the value of a class instance in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Staff> allStaffs = new ArrayList<>();
allStaffs.add (new Staff("Jason", 1, "012323787", 987, 2300, "Computers"));
```

I want to update one of the fields in that instance. Like the name "Jason".
I kept figuring this out for myself but to no avail and also tried looking for other forums.

Comment: `allStaffs.get(0).setName("Jay")`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (probably not the most efficient) is to iterate through the list until you find the instance you want to update:

```
for(Staff staff :  allStaffs){
    if (staff.getName().equals("Jason")){
        // here "staff" is that instance:
        // staff....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which element to change in the arraylist, simple get that elemnet as below and do something like this;

```
allStaffs..get(0).setName(0,"newJason")
```

Here 0 represents the index value of the element that needs to be changed.
This code is assuming that the Staff class contains a method called setName, and that "Jason" is being set as the name property of that Class.

Also, for future reference, when you say

> "...I kept figuring this out for myself but to no avail and also tried looking for other forums."

It is always best to give an example of what you tried and what research was done by you. Also, it would be good if you share more of your code, like perhaps the Staff class which is what you are basically trying to change.

Hope you liked my answer. Please give a vote up if you did! :)